Erlang server SQS implementation
I want to access SQS service through erlang's public library erlcloud. So far I have the following :
`
    -module(server).
    -export([start/0, loop/1, handle_sqs_request/1]).

     start() ->
        application:set_env(erlcloud, aws_access_key_id,      os:getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")),
        application:set_env(erlcloud, aws_secret_access_key, os:getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")),
        application:set_env(erlcloud, aws_region, os:getenv("AWS_REGION")),
        application:ensure_all_started(erlcloud),
        spawn(fun() -> loop("queueurl") end).

    loop(QueueUrl) ->
        io:format("Fetching messages from queue: ~s~n", [QueueUrl]),
        handle_sqs_request(QueueUrl),
        timer:sleep(5000),  % Wait for 5 seconds before checking again
        loop(QueueUrl).

    handle_sqs_request(QueueUrl) ->
        io:format("Processing messages from queue: ~s~n", [QueueUrl]),
        Options = #{max_number_of_messages => 10},
        io:format("Options being passed: ~p~n", [Options]),
        case erlcloud_sqs:receive_message(QueueUrl, Options) of
             {ok, Messages} ->
                io:format("Raw messages received: ~p~n", [Messages]),
                lists:foreach(fun(Msg) ->
                    case maps:get(<<"receipt_handle">>, Msg, undefined) of
                        undefined -> 
                            io:format("No receipt handle found in message: ~p~n", [Msg]);
                        ReceiptHandle ->
                            io:format("Deleting message with receipt handle: ~s~n", [ReceiptHandle]),
                            erlcloud_sqs:delete_message(QueueUrl, ReceiptHandle)
                    end
                end, Messages),
                ok;
            {error, Reason} ->
                io:format("Error receiving messages: ~p~n", [Reason])
        end.
`

and it gives the following error after rebar3 shell :

1> server:start().
Fetching messages from queue: queurl
<0.226.0>
Processing messages from queue: queuurl
Options being passed: #{max_number_of_messages => 10}
=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Dec-2024::17:07:24.378596 ===
Error in process <0.226.0> with exit value:
{function_clause,
    [{erlcloud_sqs,receive_message,
         ["queurul",
          #{max_number_of_messages => 10},
          1,none,none,
          [all],

this is my rebar.config
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [
    {erlcloud, {git, "https://github.com/erlcloud/erlcloud.git", {branch, "master"}}}
]}.
{shell, [
    {apps, [appname]}
]}.


`
The aws credentials are being correctly loaded from environment variables and match the credentials in my aws configuration, also the user has the right permissions to intreact with sqs service. queurl is hardcoded however in this example i switched it to 'queurl' for security purposes. Im using the latest version of erlcloud, however I dont seem to match the right syntax for erlcloud integration.
Can someone help me? thank you!
I tried changing back and forth the syntax of the used handle_sqs_request.
I tried older version of erlcloud but also missmatch. In my CLI im correctly sending and fetching messages from SQS so the problem is for sure in the code.

The function erlcloud_sqs:receive_message can be called with a varying number of arguments, from one to seven.  As far as I can see, if you want to specify the maximum number of messages you'd want the three-argument one. It expects the following arguments:

the queue name
attribute names, either a list or the atom all
either the maximum number of messages, or an aws_config record

So this might work:
erlcloud_sqs:receive_message(QueueUrl, all, 10)

